# How to Intercept clicks and swipes of a material design tabs in a viewpager with fragments

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

I have implemented the material design tabs as shown in [c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-viewpager-tablayout-floatingactionbutton-supportacti/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-viewpager-tablayout-floatingactionbutton-supportacti/) and added 3 more tabs.

It works fine but I need to verify the input data of the user on the first 4 tabs/fragments to allow the user to select the last tab/fragment (= the fifth which makes calculations and shows the results). When i.e. input data on the second tab/fragment is not valid, the app has to go to that tab/fragment and notify the user to correct the input data.

I tried several ways to select the corresponding fragment, tab or viewpager but they all fail and some of them crash the app. As a newbie with Xamarin I just can not figure out how to do it and after 3 days of searching on the internet, I hope that someone here can help me out.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried? which includes your fragments your viewpager adapter and your activity you hold those fragment in.

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine but I need to verify the input data of the user on the first 4 tabs/fragments to allow the user to select the last tab/fragment (= the fifth which makes calculations and shows the results). When i.e. input data on the second tab/fragment is not valid, the app has to go to that tab/fragment and notify the user to correct the input data.

You can use `ViewPager.PageSelected` event to do that:

1. Firstly, make your adapter and viewpager global to your activity:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
   {
       ViewPager viewpager;
       Adapter mAdapter;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. In `SetupViewPager` method of the tutorial you posted register the event:

   ```
   void setupViewPager(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager viewPager)
   {
       mAdapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);
       ...
       //register the event
       viewpager.PageSelected += Viewpager_PageSelected;
   }
   ```
3. Implement the event:

   ```
   private void Viewpager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
   {
        //if user is navigating to the 4th page(position start from 0)
       if (e.Position == 3)
       {
           //unregister the event first to let it not in a infinite loop.
           viewpager.PageSelected -= Viewpager_PageSelected;
           var etInput = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etInput);
           int tmp;
           //if user didn't enter a number then go back
           if (!int.TryParse(etInput.Text,out tmp))
           {
               viewpager.CurrentItem = 0;
           }
           viewpager.PageSelected += Viewpager_PageSelected;
       }
   }
   ```

**Update:**

You can have a try of my demo [here](https://github.com/elvisxia/TabLayoutDemo).

And there is something more needs to be mentioned. You need to save and update the states of controls in fragment then make it public like this(Directly call `FindViewById<EditText>` cause problem, sometimes you won't get it as the adapter may hide it for performance reason):

```
public class TabFragment1 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    //make the currentText public so that you can retrieve it later in activity
    public string CurrentText { get; set; }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TabLayout1, container, false);
        var etInput=v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etInput);
        etInput.TextChanged += EtInput_TextChanged;
        return v;
    }

    private void EtInput_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //save the EditText's text
        this.CurrentText = ((EditText)sender).Text;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve it in your activity:

```
private void Viewpager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Position == 3)
    {
        viewpager.PageSelected -= Viewpager_PageSelected;
        var text = (mAdapter.fragments[0] as TabFragment1).CurrentText;
        int tmp;
        if (!int.TryParse(text, out tmp))
        {
            viewpager.CurrentItem = 0;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please input a number in Fragment1", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        viewpager.PageSelected += Viewpager_PageSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only if you swipe the screen with your finger or mouse. But if you click directly on a tab it does not work....

Comment: You can have a try of my demo, and there are some tricks needs to be implemented, please check my updates.

Comment: Have you tried my demo and does it work for direct tab? Because by my side, it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Elvis. My problem is not retrieving the data on the individual fragments. All the data in my app is stored in a global object so I can retrieve and verify it quit simple. But I still can not intercept the click events on the tabs to verify the data. So I am searching for a event listener for the tabs like you mentioned for the viewpager with the code "viewpager.PageSelected += Viewpager_PageSelected;".

Comment: I'm not talking about retrieving the data on the individual fragments. There is no 100% interception for user to navigating to the fragment. But you can force user to navigate back(for example to navigate back to fragment 1),if user has input a false data or wrong data type. if you have tried my demo, you will see.

Comment: Hi Elvis,

Thans for your reply. I implemented your code but it does not work if I click on a tab. It only works when I swipe the screen with my finger or mouse.

Comment: Could you please share your implementation project through online repo? I'll look into it.

Comment: Hi Elvis, there was a small error in the code that I had implemented. Now your code is working. GREAT and THANKS!